# Is .NET Framework v4.0.30128 the latest version?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I have .NET Framework v4.0.30128 installed on my server. Is it the latest one?

If not, should I install the latest version?

Comment: I think this was the RC version >_>

Comment: Note for those who find this through Google after May 2010 ... v4.0.30128 was the RC version; 4.0.30319 the original release edition for v4. You can always get the latest version directly from Microsoft here: http://www.microsoft.com/net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not.  You should replace it with the release version, which is 4.0.30319.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the older version to install the latest?

Comment: @Amitabh You most likely have a beta or RC version installed, so uninstalling would be advisable...

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow it could be change. The best would be to have a link with the last versions (framework, Visual Studio, SQL Server, etc.). Does it exist ?

Comment: What could change? That's the RTM

Comment: ok now it is the RTM and in a few times there will be SP1 then SP2 and the version number will change. The most important is to have an updated list where we can see what is the last version number.